# Applications of powerful theorems in Bruns -Herzog's book "Cohen-Macaulay Rings"

Tags: commutative-algebra, soft-question, big-list, cohen-macaulay

It seems that theorem 1.4.13 and it's corollary of Bruns and Herzog's book *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*, are powerful tools but I don't see any example that shows the power of it. My original question was an example that shows the power of it in use, but I change it as you see below to be more useful for me and others:

> **What is your favorite *powerful* theorem in commutative algebra**, especially in the book *Cohen-Macaulay Rings* by Bruns and Herzog?

Please **give an example that shows the power of it in use**, with a hint that shows the *application* of that theorem  in that example.

Comment: I haven't read Bruns-Herzog, but a lot of the interesting results in Eisenbud's _The Geometry of Syzygies_ rely on the fact that $k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$ is C-M. One reason is that Green's work in the 80s connects syzygies to the cohomology of the Koszul complex, which is very connected to depth.

Answer (score 2):

[Auslander--Buchsbaum formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslander-Buchsbaum_formula).
  example: as "11156" says "everybody who read commutative algebra knows examples", but for example:
**Matt E**'s solution for my question: ([R is a regular local ring of dimension $d$, and $I$ an ideal. If $R/I$ has depth $d − 1$, then $I$ is principal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792550/r-is-a-regular-local-ring-of-dimension-d-and-i-an-ideal-if-r-a-has-depth/792584#792584))

Answer (score 1):

> **Theorem** $1.2.5$ (Rees). Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $M$ a finite $R$-module, and $I$ an ideal such that $IM\neq M$. Then all maximal $M$-sequences in $I$ have the same length $n$ given by 
>   $$n=\min \{i: \operatorname{Ext}^i_R(R/I,M)\neq 0\}.$$

It's extremely useful. It has many applications in commutative algebra, local cohomology,... and even dont need an example of usefulness. Everyone who studies commutative algebra knows examples.