# R is a regular local ring of dimension $d$, and $I$ an ideal. If $R/I$ has depth $d − 1$, then $I$ is principal.

Tags: commutative-algebra

is this true?

> $R$ is a regular local ring of dimension $d$, and $I$ an ideal.
>   If $R/I$ has depth $d − 1$, then $I$ is principal.

if it is true please help me by a hint

Comment: Do you mean $R/I$ has depth $d-1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Try using the [Auslander--Buchsbaum formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslander-Buchsbaum_formula).

Comment: so $I$ is free, and  every free ideal is principal

Comment: Dear 313, Yes.  Regards,